# How can I condense these jQuery codes?

Tags: jquery

I'm still learning how to write jQuery efficiently, but for this instance, I could use a little expertise. What's the best means of condensing the jQuery codes below:

```
  $('#nav .wsite-nav-1 a').click(function() {
    $('#nav .wsite-nav-1 a').addClass('show');
  }, function() {
    $('#nav .wsite-nav-1 a').removeClass('show');
  });

  $('#nav .wsite-nav-2 a').click(function() {
    $('#nav .wsite-nav-2 a').addClass('show');
  }, function() {
    $('#nav .wsite-nav-2 a').removeClass('show');
  });

  $('#nav .wsite-nav-3 a').click(function() {
    $('#nav .wsite-nav-3 a').addClass('show');
  }, function() {
    $('#nav .wsite-nav-3 a').removeClass('show');
  });

  $('#nav .wsite-nav-4 a').click(function() {
    $('#nav .wsite-nav-4 a').addClass('show');
  }, function() {
    $('#nav .wsite-nav-4 a').removeClass('show');
  });
```

Comment: Take a look at https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass

Comment: for reviewing code efficiency like this, the codereview stack exchange is a pretty cool starting place https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Along with toggleClass you could also probably get away with just using the class name i.e. $('.wsite-nav-2')

Comment: `.click()` doesn't take two callback arguments, your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why not give your `wsite-nav` containers a common class instead?

Comment: @h2ooooooo But he only wants to toggle the ones that have the same class as the one he clicks on.

Comment: Until the logic works without error, it's off topic for codereview.  @Marker

Comment: True, but the question itself is solely asking if this is the best method

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback! With it, I reworked the coding to such:
  $('#nav .wsite-menu-item-wrap a').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('show');
  });

Comment: I understand that, but if you tell them to take this to codereview, and they do, I would not be surprised if it was closed over there.  And then they have wasted their time.

Comment: @Barmar Could rather easily be done with `$('elem').getParents('.nav:eq(0)')` assuming there's a common class. It seems op just wanted to change `$(this)` though.

Comment: @Weebs You should post that as an answer, not a comment. Also, it would only work if there's just one element that needs to be toggled. The question never indicates that there's just one element that matches each selector. It toggles *all* the elements that match the same selector as the one you click on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help and recommendations from above, I was able to construct my own answer - thanks everyone! I used a common class and switched to toggleClass as opposed to addClass and removeClass for condensing:

```
$('#nav .wsite-menu-item-wrap a').click(function() { 
  $(this).toggleClass('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the above task by the following condensed jQuery code:

```
var links = $("#nav").find("a");
  links.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass("show")){
        $(this).removeClass("show");
    }else{
        $(this).addClass("show");
    }
  });
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: The OP has a more condensed version they came up with themselves in the comments.

Comment: @Taplar okay yeah.. cool.. just read it, that solution is more cooler..

Comment: @Taplar, I read today in a question today that `toggle()` event is deprecated in the latest version of the jquery, cant remember the link though. Here is the link: [toggle event deprecated in jquery version 1.8](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ vs http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ , the second of which is deprecated and removed.  The first is not.  @Code_Ninja

Comment: Your `if` is just doing what `$(this).toggleClass("show")` does.

Comment: Read the above comments @Barmar, i had a misunderstanding with deprecated API.

Comment: What does deprecation of `toggle` have to do with `toggleClass`?

Comment: @Barmar.. i have said already.. that i was confused with any function that has toggle. Now get off my back.